# How to handle exceptions for Numpy modules in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am new to Python development. I want to know how to handle the exception for Numpy module.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try` and `except`:

```
try:
  (your statements...)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```